Installing 32bit windows on 64bit uefi only device via grub 2
I have a weired chinese cherrytrain tablet which seems to be supporting 64 bit uefi boot only.
since it has only 4gigs of ram, I want to use this machine with 32 bit windows 10(yes, I know 4gigs also works fine with 64 bit windows, but it's just matter of feeling). but it won't boot and just goes back to cmos setup menu.
then I found out that grub2 may help bypassing 32bit/64bit issues, but I found documents about installing 64bit os on 32 bit uefi and what i'm trying to do is reverese of these.
Is this 'installing 32bit windows on 64bit uefi via grub' possible? if so, is there a guideline that I can start with?

32-bit Windows has never done well booting from a 64-bit UEFI kernel. If your processor supports 64-bit operating system is there a reason other than “feeling” to not run a 64-bit operating system?

If such a weak device supports it, try a virtual machine. Free VirtualBox can happily run a 32-bit OS within Windows 10 64-bit, for example, and I've used that to create 32-bit rescue media for an old laptop.
